# How do I “flatten” a list of lists in perl 6?

Tags: raku

Let's say I want all permutations of 2 letters out of a, b and c.

I can do:

```
my @perm = <a b c>.combinations(2)».permutations;
say @perm;
# [((a b) (b a)) ((a c) (c a)) ((b c) (c b))]
```

which is close, but not exactly what I need.
How do I “flatten” this so that I get:

```
# [(a b) (b a) (a c) (c a) (b c) (c b)]
```

?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166662/perl-what-is-the-easiest-way-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array

Comment: @FuePi, not at all.  Perl 5 ≠ Perl 6.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See also ["a better way to accomplish what I (OP) wanted"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37173023/how-do-i-flatten-a-list-of-lists-in-perl-6/37230217#comment65432792_39019357).

See also ["Some possible solutions" answer to "How can I completely flatten a Raku list (of lists (of lists) … )" question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41649110/1077672).

## Add a subscript

```perl6
my \perm = <a b c>.combinations(2)».permutations;
say perm;       # (((a b) (b a)) ((a c) (c a)) ((b c) (c b)))
say perm[*];    # (((a b) (b a)) ((a c) (c a)) ((b c) (c b)))
say perm[*;*];  # ((a b) (b a) (a c) (c a) (b c) (c b))
say perm[*;*;*] # (a b b a a c c a b c c b)
```

### Notes

I used a non-sigil'd variable because I think it's a bit clearer what's going on for those who don't know Raku.

I didn't append the subscript to the original expression but I could have:

```perl6
my \perm = <a b c>.combinations(2)».permutations[*;*];
say perm;       # ((a b) (b a) (a c) (c a) (b c) (c b))
```

Comment: I like the `[*;*]` trick to “flatten” the list of lists!  I don't like the sigil-less variable, though, which is a lot *less* clear for those of us who *do* know Perl (5 or 6).

Comment: @Larry's [speculation/specification of multidimensional arrays](http://design.perl6.org/S09.html#Multidimensional_arrays) makes interesting reading. Some of the simpler parts of it like this "trick" have already been implemented in v6.c and the Rakudo Perl 6 compiler.

Answer (score 10):

Ultimately, you are building your list the wrong way to begin with. You can `slip` your permutations into the outer list like this.

```
<a b c>.combinations(2).map(|*.permutations);
```

Which yields the following list

```
((a b) (b a) (a c) (c a) (b c) (c b))
```

According to the [Bench](https://github.com/tony-o/perl6-bench) module, this is about 300% faster than doing

```
<a b c>.combinations(2).map(*.permutations)[*;*]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed a better way to accomplish what I wanted.  I'm not marking this as the best answer, though, because it isn't strictly an answer to the question I asked.  :)

Answer (score 9):

By inserting [slips](http://doc.perl6.org/type/Slip) as appropriate, eg via

```
<a b c>.combinations(2).map(*.permutations.Slip).Array
```

or

```
[ slip .permutations for <a b c>.combinations(2) ]
```

Invoking `.Array` in the first example is unnecessary if you're fine with a `Seq`, and can be replaced with calls to `.list` or `.cache` (supplied by [PositionalBindFailover](http://doc.perl6.org/type/Seq#Routines_supplied_by_role_PositionalBindFailover)) if mutability is not needed.

In the second example, the prefix `|` operator could be used instead of the `slip` sub.

Comment: `».` and `map` are not equivalent. The former is a candidate for auto-threading. Creating a LoL with one less level may not be what he wants.

Comment: @gfldex: you can always throw in a `.hyper` call if that's what you want; also note that in your example, the list of combinations gets iterated twice

Comment: Thanks, `.Slip` is the trick I needed.  Too bad that `».Slip` doesn't seem to work...

Comment: @mscha: hyperoperators descend into nested structures, so you're slipping the single-element leaves, which is a noop

Comment: @Christoph, I don't think that is true, otherwise the `».permutations` part wouldn't have worked either.

Comment: @mscha: that's because the `permutations` method is annotated with the `nodal` trait (cf `Any.pm`, `List.pm`), which prevents hyper operators from performing a deep map (cf `metaops.pm`, look for `METAOP_HYPER_POSTFIX`); not sure if this is explained in the user documentation, but it's mentioned [in the design docs](http://design.perl6.org/S03.html#Unary_hyper_operators)

Answer (score 5):

```
my @perm = <a b c>.combinations(2)».permutations;
dd [ @perm.map(*.Slip) ]
# OUTPUT«[("a", "b"), ("b", "a"), ("a", "c"), ("c", "a"), ("b", "c"), ("c", "b")]␤»
```

However, you may be better of to destructure the LoL when you use it later in the program. A map on a long list can take a jolly long time.

Comment: Thanks, `.Slip` is the trick I needed.  Too bad that `».Slip` doesn't seem to work...