# Recursivly flatten a multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, raku

What's the shortest way to flat a multidimensional array?
Here's some examples of what I mean:

```
# 2D array
my @a = [1,2],[3,4];
say @a».Slip.flat;                # prints (1 2 3 4)
# 3D array
my @b = [[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]];
say @b».Slip».flat».Slip.flat;    # prints (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)
                                  # but needs to know how many dimensions
                                  # there are to flatten
```

Is it possible to recursively flatten an array of arrays such as `@b` without writing a sub which recursively descends into it or having any knowledge of the number of its dimensions?
I'm asking this because I trust the compiler (now or in a future implementation) to be able to optimize more an operator-based solution than a sub.

Comment: One day you'll be able to use `[**]`. For now, you could use `[*;*;*;*;*]` (you can specify more dimensions than actually exist). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37230217/1077672 Do you think your question is a duplicate of one of the linked questions or warrants its own answer?

Comment: @raiph that's documented, but it's not indexed: https://docs.perl6.org/language/subscripts#Multiple_dimensions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure if there's a more compact way, but

```
say do gather @b.deepmap(*.take);
```

should do it.

If you do not care for the order of the flattened result,

```
say do gather @b>>.take;
```

might also be an option, though it 'feels' wrong to me to (ab)use hyper operators for side effects...

---

Until proper handling of HyperWhatever slicing suggested by raiph arrives in core, you could add your own sugar `@b[**]` covering this specific use case via

```
multi sub postcircumfix:<[ ]>(\SELF, HyperWhatever:D $, *% where !*) {
    gather SELF.deepmap(*.take);
}
```

Comment: Would `sub postfix:<[**]> ($_) { gather .deepmap: *.take }` make sense? When `**` gets implemented (per my comment on Fernando's question) then, assuming it's faster, one can just remove this sub.

Comment: maybe - depends on your view of 'jagged' arrays (in contrast to shaped ones); I guess `.[**]` flattening the whole thing could make sense; the proper way to implement this would be like https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/core/array_slice.pm6#L448

Comment: having thought about this a bit, given that we're talking about perl (DWIM!) and that `.[2][3]` and `.[2;3]` both work interchangeably on jagged arrays, change that 'maybe' to 'yes'

Comment: :) .oO ( [Coming to `6.f`](http://design.perl6.org/S09.html#Mixing_subscripts): `@calendar{ July; **[0..2; *-3..*-1] } # Last three business hours of first three days in July`. )

Answer (score 0):

```
say @a>>.List.flat
```

should do the trick, however i have noticed that a Range will break the recursion:

```
my @a = [[1,2],[3,4],5,[6,7],[8,9,0],[[1,[2,3,4,[ 23,56,^7]],5,6,]],7,8,9,0];
say @a>>.List.flat;   #prints (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 [23 56 ^7] 5 6 7 8 9 0)
```

i don't know if this is a bug or not.

Comment: it's not the range that does it, but the level of depth - see eg `say [[[[1,],],],]>>.List.flat`

Comment: indeed you're right.  can you explain where this nesting level limit comes from ?  it's not obvious to me.

Comment: I didn't look at the code to verify, but what seems to happen is that `>>.List` will listify only the first sub-level of the array (ie it does not descend recursively) by virtue of the operation you passed to the hyper as well as the top level for a reason I'm not quite clear on (I would have expected the top-level to remain an Array); these first two levels will be transparent to the call to `.flat`, which will then flatten out another level of depth; however, that's where it stops if that last level was an array, as its elements are held in scalar containers, which are items