# How to make a list of 2-element lists into a hash?

Tags: raku

I have a list of two-element lists, like what you'd get for example by `(1..5) Z (20..24)`, that I want to make into a hash (in this example, what you get by `{1 => 20, 2 => 21, 3 => 22, 4 => 23, 5 =>24}`. I could do it "by hand", but that isn't too elegant, and I'm sure Raku has a idiomatic way of doing it. The inelegant alternative I come up with is:

```
my @a = (1..5) Z (20..24);
my %a;
for @a -> @x {
   %a{@x[0]} = @x[1];
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
my %h = (1..5) Z=> (20..24);
say %h;  # {1 => 20, 2 => 21, 3 => 22, 4 => 23, 5 => 24}
```

The `Z` meta-operator takes an operator as part of its name, and it defaults to `,`, thus creating lists by default.  If you add the `Pair` constructor (aka fat-comma), then you create a list of `Pair`s, which you can feed into a `Hash`.

An alternate solution would be to `flat`ten the result of `Z`:

```
my %h = flat (1..5) Z (20..24);
```

Comment: For this particular example, this works fine. But what if I got the list of two-element lists somehow else?

Comment: @vonbrand The flattening strategy is fully general. `flat` will flatten multiple levels of a multi-level data structure if the levels are `List`s. But if you've already introduced non-`List`s, eg assigning the data to an `Array` without using `flat` *before* doing so, then `flat` will no longer be the right tool. For example, if you've assigned it using `my @a = 1..5 Z 20..25;` then `flat` alone won't do the job. I would flatten it like this `my %h = @a[*;*];`. I've written a bit more about using subscripts to flatten out multi-level data [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37230217/1077672).

Comment: @ralph, what about `((1, (1, 2, 3)), (2, (5, 6)), (17, (3, 4, 5, 92, 31))` (i.e., the end result would be a hash with lists as values)?