# Accessing the values in an array of lists of pairs

Tags: hashmap, raku

```
my @products = (
    (name => "samsung s6" , price => "600"),
    (name => "samsung s7" , price => "700"));

# for @products -> $x { say $x{"name"} ~ ": USD" ~ $x{"price"} };

# Desired output:
#
# samsung s6: USD600
# samsung s7: USD700

# Real output: An error:
#
# "Type List does not support associative indexing."
```

I would also like to iterate using the `.kv` method and the  `$key` and `$val` like so:

```
for @products -> $x.kv -> $key,$val  { say $x{$key} ~ " " ~ $x{$val} };

# That gives a "Malformed parameter" error
```

I've looked up the Raku documentation but this particular case isn't mentioned in the documentation. How to do it?
Alternative ways or improvisation on the code are welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's always important to make your data structures right.  In this case, they don't feel right, but I guess you are forced to use that format.  In any case, I would solve it like this:

```
for @products.map( { |(.[0].value, .[1].value) } ) -> $name, $price {
```

In words: map the list with pairs to a Slip (prefix `|`) with just the values of the pairs, and feed that into `$name` and `$price` two elements at a time.  Perhaps better readable would be:

```
for @products.map( { (.[0].value, .[1].value).Slip } ) -> $name, $price {
```

Comment: I need to or I'd prefer to use that data structure because a problem came up which was written in Python and there the data was expressed similar to that.  The `|` is also known as `flatten` operator, is that right? At the end of the day, the `map` does the trick here :)

Comment: The `|` is known as a [`Slip`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Slip).  A `Slip` is a `List` that will automatically iterate when inserted into an iteration.  But it does **not** flatten its elements.  [flat](https://docs.raku.org/type/Iterable#method_flat) does.

Comment: Liz, you could use the `Pair`-as-named-arg version of the thing you did for the prior SO about a list of `Pair`s: `for @products -> (:$name, :$price) { say "$name: USD$price" }`.

Answer (score 5):

For the data given, you can use this sub-signature:

```raku
for @products -> @ ( :$name, :$price ) {
  say "$name: USD$price"
}
```

So this expects a single unnamed listy argument `@`.
It then expounds upon that by saying it contains two named values.
(This works because you have them as Pair objects.)

---

Really what you had was very close to working, all you had to do was coerce to a Hash.

```raku
for @products -> $x { say $x.hash{"name"} ~ ": USD" ~ $x.hash{"price"} }

for @products -> Hash() $x { say $x{"name"} ~ ": USD" ~ $x{"price"} }
```

---

Personally if I were going to do a lot of work with this data I would create an ecosystem for it.

```raku
class Product {
  has $.name;
  has $.price;

  our sub from-JSON-list ( @ (:$name, :$price) --> ::?CLASS ) {
    ::?CLASS.new( :$name, :$price )
  }

  method gist ( --> Str ) { "$.name: USD$.price" }
}


@products .= map: &Product::from-JSON-list;

.say for @products;
```

If you didn't like the `&` you could create a constant alias to the sub.

```raku
…

  constant from-JSON-list =
  our sub from-JSON-list ( @ (:$name, :$price) ) {
    ::?CLASS.new( :$name, :$price )
  }

…

@products .= map: Product::from-JSON-list;
```

Comment: Nice answer. Just to mention that the raku eco system has some help for that ... https://modules.raku.org/search/?q=JSON ... personally I would lean to JSON::Class.

Answer (score 3):

Since raku OO is so lightweight, you *could* use a class which is a great way to manage non-uniform data structures:

```
class Product {
    has $.name;
    has $.price;

    method gist { "$.name: USD$.price" }
}

my @products = ( 
    Product.new(name => "samsung s6" , price => "600"),
    Product.new(name => "samsung s6" , price => "600"),
);
.say for @products;

#samsung s6: USD600
#samsung s6: USD600
```

Comment: Thank you for the alternative solution for the data structure. However, the code  was originally written in Python and the data structure therein was written in a JSON-like notation. I had to use its counterpart in Raku and solve it using that notation.

Comment: Ah OK - I wasn’t sure whether to show a load() sub and see that Brad has done a good job on that below...

Answer (score 2):

Great answers already. Brad's `Hash()` coercion solution is so sweet!

But it felt like another answer was called for. No one directly discussed your impulse to go the key/value route using `.kv`, and the error you got:

> I would also like to iterate using the `.kv` method ... "Malformed parameter"

## `.kv` isn't helpful because of the nature of your data

Your data is such that `.kv` just isn't going to help you get where you need to go. (Which is why no one used it.)

Why not?

Here's your data:

```
    (name => "samsung s6" , price => "600"),
    (name => "samsung s7" , price => "700"),
    ...
```

Each element in `@products` is a sub-list of two key/value pairs.

*But **all** of the **keys** are **useless***!

What you really want to do is *throw away* the existing *keys* and then construct *brand new pairs* by treating the *value* of the first pair in each `@products` element as a *new* key and the *value* of the second pair as the associated *value*.

So you end up with something like:

```
("samsung s6" => "600"),
("samsung s7" => "700"),
```

To do this you need to forget `.kv`.

Instead you need to suitably combine something like a `.value` routine with a `.pairup` routine. And indeed that works:

```
.say for @products[*;*]».value.pairup
```

displays:

```
samsung s6 => 600
samsung s7 => 700
```

Let's break that down:

```
.say for @products[*;*]
```

displays:

```
name => samsung s6
price => 600
name => samsung s7
price => 700
```

For an explanation of what the `[*;*]` is doing, see [my answer to **How do I “flatten” a list of lists?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37230217/1077672).

As already explained, the keys are useless. We want the *value* from each `Pair`:

```
.say for @products[*;*]».value
```

displays:

```
samsung s6
600
samsung s7
700
```

A `»` in this scenario is like an inner `for` loop, or a `map`. For example, I could have written:

```
.value.say for (do @$_ for @products[*;*])
```

But it's a lot easier to write just the one character `»`. This gets rid of the extra parens, inner `for` construct, and what not.

Finally we tack a `.pairup` on the end to pair up odd and even elements of a list; each *odd* element becomes a key, and the following (even) element becomes the associated value. Job done.

## About the error message

The error message includes an `⏏`. This is an "eject" symbol, pinpointing where the parser gave up:

```
------> for @products -> $x⏏.kv
```

The words "Malformed parameter" are calling out the `.` in your code:

```
for @products -> $x.kv ...
```

The `$x` has been parsed as a parameter, or at least the start of one. But then what's with the `.`? It might be invoking a method call if it were part of an expression, but here you should be finishing up specifying the name of a parameter. So the parser bails.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting the error is you are constructing a `List` of `List`s of `Pair`s but treating it as a `List` of `Hash`es.

The simplest fix for the code is to update the data structure to match how you are treating it :

```
my @products = (
    {name => "samsung s6" , price => "600"},
    {name => "samsung s7" , price => "700"}
);
```

The `{}` in this case is evaluated as a `Hash` constructor. I think the issue arises with the fact that in Raku `=>` is a `Pair` constructor as opposed to a special comma.

As others have suggested a light weight Object can be useful too but I think it's good to understand how to build what you *thought* you were building.