# How to flatten a multidimensinal array in perl?

Tags: perl

I am trying to flatten a multidimensional array shown below.

```
@arr = ([1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]);
$ref = \@arr;
@a = map {@$_} @$ref;
print "@a";
```

But what about if and array ref contains another array ref in it as shown below.
    @arr = ([1,2,3,4,[a,b]],[5,6,7,8]);

Comment: Specifically, [List::Flatten::Recursive](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aFlatten%3a%3aRecursive)'s `flat` or the sub [provided](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20359734/589924) by Garen.