# Cannot have plain array after removal ones in multi dimensional array

Tags: arrays, perl

How do we have plain array after ones in multi dimensional array are removed ?

```
@p=();
my @l=([9,7],[3,4]);

push(@p,['FOO',[@l]]);
push(@p,['BAR',[[8,0]]]);
splice(@$_,0,1) for @p;
print "\n",@$_ for @p;

ARRAY(0x5624cf01e340)
ARRAY(0x5624cf028d78)
```

How do we have it simple/plain 2D array with number of 1x2 size on inner/2nd dimensional one. In other words, how linearize it to such?

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are saying. What does `D. one. IOW` mean?

Comment: Note: This question was cross-posted to https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=11139965

Comment: Can you show us the final array that you'd like to get to?

Answer (score 5):

Have to de-reference elements which are array-references, and copy data. For a single level:

```
@ary = map { ref eq "ARRAY" ? @$_ : $_ } @ary;
```

The [ref](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref) builtin by default takes `$_`.  Also consider using `reftype` from [Scalar::Util](https://metacpan.org/pod/Scalar::Util), instead.  Then also look into `is_arrayref` from [Ref::Util](https://metacpan.org/pod/Ref::Util).  In simple and straighforward cases the builtin is fine.

In case there are deeper levels use the above on each level. For the question's quest, to retain one level of nesting from the two-level deep input data:

```
for my $elem (@p) { 
    @$elem = map { ref eq "ARRAY" ? @$_ : $_ } @$elem;
}
```

Since `$elem` aliases the current element of `@p` this code changes the array in place.

If there are further levels, of possibly varying depth, can handle that either recursively or iteratively.  Crude implementations:

Recursive:

```
sub flatten_recurse { 
    return map { ref eq 'ARRAY' ? flatten_recurse(@$_) : $_ } @_ 
}
```

This could be expensive on large data structures (but worry only if that is indeed the case).

Iterative:

```
sub flatten_iter { 
    my @deque = @_; 
    my @flat;
    while (@deque) {
        my $front = shift @deque;
        if (ref($front) eq 'ARRAY') {
            unshift @deque, @$front;
        } else {
            push @flat, $front;
        }
    }   
    return \@flat;
}
```

Here one can also use `pop` and `push`, in varying combinations. The above keeps the order, as much as that makes sense when reducing a complex structure to a flattened one.

If there are yet other complexities, like other types of references (themselves containing arrayrefs to be unpacked), then this need be adjusted accordingly.  One would also need to add checks, in particular for circular references.  See for instance [this SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5166662/4653379) and [this perlmonks page](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=308274).